# Article in the phrase "Added [article] basic support ..."

Tags: articles

Suppose I've written some code and added a feature which now allows our application to support some Apple device (I've made it all up just to provide some context). Now I'm writing a concise report for what I've done. How would I write the phrase?

1. Added basic Apple support ...
2. Added a basic Apple support ...
3. Added the basic Apple support ...

The question apeared because everyone I know (non-native speakers), including myself, like the first variant. But no one can tell me why and it appears that Google like the 3rd one.

Which is correct and why?

**UPD:**

It all started with the following sentence: "Added [a/the/] basic user interface support for the tasks feature". I was inclined to use no articles at all but then I became doubtful, went for the rules, found nothing to support my gut feeling and used "the".

Comment: To me, it seems that option 1 works best, especially if the sentence ends with "support". It would be great to see the full sentence. A google search for `"added * support" computer` brings up instances similar to your option 1. It seems felicitous to use no article in this construction in such technical reports.

Comment: @CopperKettle, added an example

Comment: I would use no article in your example sentence, but let's wait for native speaker's opinions.

Comment: Google? Google search, or some Google style guide? Anyhow, it's not like code reports need to be grammatical. They hire you to speak computer, not English. ;)

Comment: @modulusshift, the phrase was used in a commit description not in a report but it is irrelevant since I want to know for myself and not because I'd lke to please someone with "perfect grammar". As to Google: I meant search — "Add the basic support" gives more results and on the first page there are at least 2 books with such a phrase. Search without an article and with "a" give less results and no books on the first page.

Comment: If you want to know more about article usage, I'd recommend Quirk et al.'s book "A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language". I've never read a more thorough description of article usage.

Comment: @CopperKettle, thank you I'll definitely take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the key thing to consider is the issue of countability.

When a noun is countable and singular, in most cases it should take an article: either **a** or **the**. The problem with English is that a noun can be countable in one sense and uncountable in some other sense. Here's a **[dictionary entry for 'support'](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/support_2)** that lists its countable and uncountable senses.

The majority of the listed senses for **support** are uncountable, and only two are countable:

> [countable] a thing that holds something and prevents it from falling.
>
> [countable] something you wear to hold an injured or weak part of your body firmly in position

These countable senses clearly do not fit your purpose, and it's only a countable singular **support** that can take **a**:

> John installed **a support** in the coal mine to make it safer.
>
> John wears **a knee support** to help him walk.

---

The two examples of **support** above are countable; your **support** is uncountable, because its meaning leans towards "function", not some palpable, material thing. This sentence would sound strange:

> This year, I've **added Apple supports** to ten different applications. (a bit strange)

You would say instead:

> This year, I've **added Apple support** to ten different applications.

Compare with a countable-sense **support**:

> This year, I've **installed wooden supports** in ten different coal mines.

---

When a noun is uncountable, it either takes **the** or takes no article. In order to take **the**, it should be *definite*. It's hard for me to expand your sentence to make it "definite enough", but I'll try:

> We also added **the** basic Apple support **that the customer requested last month.** (the noun **support** is definite because we used the "that-clause" to make it definite)

But this sentence seems somewhat strange to me. It's more usual to use **support** in this context as a indefinite non-count noun:

> We also added **basic Apple support**, as requested by the customer last month.

---

Examples of usage from Google Books:

> HTML 4.01 1999 This version **added support for** style sheets to give Web designers greater control over page layout. ([source](https://books.google.ru/books?id=4-BlHT9Xb1oC&lpg=PA6&dq=%22added%20support%20for%22&hl=ru&pg=PA6#v=onepage&q=%22added%20support%20for%22&f=false))
>
> A variant of 95b, called OSR 2.1, **added rudimentary USB support**. ([source](https://books.google.ru/books?id=BLjomivi1asC&lpg=PA182&dq=%22added%20*%20support%22%20computer&hl=ru&pg=PA182#v=onepage&q=%22added%20*%20support%22%20computer&f=false))
>
> Besides **expanded support** and improved performance of NDS, now called NDS eDirectory, Novell **added pure IP support**. ([source](https://books.google.ru/books?id=1nxVQVyNdzsC&lpg=PA227&dq=%22added%20*%20support%22%20computer&hl=ru&pg=PA227#v=onepage&q=pure%20ip%20support&f=false))

Furthermore, [Google Ngram finds no instances of "added **a** support for", but does find instances of "added support for"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=added+support+for%2C+added+a+support+for&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cadded%20support%20for%3B%2Cc0).

---

(a caveat: I'm not a native speaker of English, and articles are cryptic to me sometimes)